# Is it possible to put multiple pages in an InfoWindow - ArcGIS API 3.27

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I noticed that when you use IdentifyTask to identify features at a given point on the map, it shows an InfoWindow with multiple pages. I was wondering if it was possible to add pages to an InfoWindow without explicitly having to select an area with multiple features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a little bit of a hack, taking advantage of the InfoWindow's feature display to add multiple pages. You're essentially tricking it into believing you've clicked an area with multiple features.

```
var fakeFeatures = [];
var page1 = {
    getLayer: function () {}, // as long as it returns null, you're good
    attributes: {}, // this does not influence the content in the popup
    getInfoTemplate: function () {
        return { title: "test", content: "${*}", declaredClass: "esri.InfoTemplate" };
    // yes, you do need 'declaredClass', otherwise the title will not show up
    },
    getTitle: function () { return this.getInfoTemplate().title; },
    getContent: function () { return "HTML</br>" }
};
fakeFeatures.push(page1);

var page2 = {
    getLayer: function () {},
    attributes: {},
    getInfoTemplate: function () {
        return { title: "test", content: "${*}", declaredClass: "esri.InfoTemplate" };
    },
    getTitle: function () { return this.getInfoTemplate().title; },
    getContent: function () { return "HTML</br>" }
};
fakeFeatures.push(page2);
map.infoWindow.setFeatures(fakeFeatures);
```